# Angular2 - stylesArr doesn' load correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 app.  This code loads my `stylesArr` correctly:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
...

import * as c3 from 'c3';

@Component({
  selector: 'open-account',
  styleUrls: ['./open-account.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './open-account.component.html',
})


export class OpenAccountComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
...
```

But when I use this code with my `stylesArr` array I get the error `http://localhost:3000/open-account.component.scss 404 (Not Found)` & `Failed to load open-account.component.scss` :

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Params } from '@angular/router';
...

import * as c3 from 'c3';

var stylesArr = ['./open-account.component.scss'];

@Component({
  selector: 'open-account',
  styleUrls: stylesArr,
  templateUrl: './open-account.component.html',
})


export class OpenAccountComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewChecked, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
...
```

Here is my file structure:

```
web-frontend
│       
│
└───src
    │   
    └───open-account
        └───index.ts
        └───open-account-widget-styles.component.scss
        └───open-account.component.html
        └───open-account.component.scss
        └───open-account.component.ts
        └───open-account.module.ts
        └───open-account.routes.ts
        └───open-account.service.ts
```

Why doesn't the second way work?  Shouldn't they function exactly the same?  (ps. I need to use the array form because I will be conditionally adding a second stylesheet to the array if there is a specific query string present in the url).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the path as

```
var stylesArr = ['/open-account.component.scss'];
```

If this does not work update your post with the folder structure

Comment: thanks but that didnt work, I updated post with my file structure

Comment: Remove the preceding slash also and update me if it is working

Comment: that did not work as well, I ended up doing this (which did work):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'open-account',
  styleUrls: ['open-account.component.scss', 'open-account-widget-styles.component.scss'].filter((elem, i) => {
    if (i === 0) return true;
    if (i === 1) {
      if (window.location.href.indexOf('widget=true') > -1) return true;
      else return false;
    }
  }),
  templateUrl: './open-account.component.html',
})
```